# Not seeing Quick Text

Tags: quickaction

I created Quick Text within an email in Salesforce Lightning.  I can't figure out how to see the Quick Text that I created.  When I create a new email & try to use Quick Text, it says there isn't any available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Quick Text option had to be enabled in Classic even though it was enabled in Lightning.